# How to retrieve application details from play store

Tags: android, google-play

I want to retrieve application details like category, price, ratings etc information and display in my list view. How can I get these details of an app? or Is there any way to retrieve all these info of an app depending on package name programmability

Comment: You can't. This information doesn't store inside apk file and Google play doesn't have official API to retrieve this data. There is only one way to parse HTML.

Comment: @Demand You don't necessarily have to parse HTML, there are unofficial APIs one can use, but of course these could stop working at any time.

Comment: @XaverKapeller The problem of all unnofficial api it's not supported. It can be changed or turned off in any moment. HTML page will always exist, it may changes but will exist. Therefore it's not good idea anyway, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think that Google has officially API for that.

But you can try [this](https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics).

Or you can write your own parser of html page.